# Validating enums with a custom FluentValidator validator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, lambda, fluentvalidation

I created a custom validator, which tests that a value is within an enum's range of valid values:

```
public class IsInEnumValidator<T> : PropertyValidator {
  public IsInEnumValidator() : base("Property {PropertyName} it not a valid enum value.") { }
  protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context) {
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) return false;
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), context.PropertyValue);
  }
}
```

And an extension method for chaining validators:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> IsInEnum<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder) {
  return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new IsInEnumValidator<TProperty>());
}
```

I want to use use it like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Day).IsInEnum<DayOfWeek>();
```

**My questions:**

1. This doesn't work as expected, as I need to speficy `....IsInEnum<T, DayOfWeek>()` instead of the desired `....IsInEnum<DayOfWeek>();`. How do I achieve this?
2. I want to test this custom validator - not to test my data with this validator, but to test the validator itself. The library's docs explain how to test your data, not how to test a custom validator. There seems to be lots of testing code in the library, is there anything I can reuse? I use NUnit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1: Because of type inference, you actually don't need to specify anything in the `IsInEnum()` call.

2: For testing, the project has lots of tests which can be adapted to fit this scneario.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 6.2 IsInEnum is built-in. 
From 6.2.1 Nullable Enums are supported.

Cheers.